# adding tooltip to datagrid headers in dojo

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I have a dojo datagrid which is poulated dynamically. I want to add tooltip to table headers of this datagrid. How can i do that?My datagrid simply has the structure of table and table headers. the fields get populated dynamically.

Thanks,
Sreenivas

Answer (score 1):

### Easiest Way

The easiest way, (Without overriding the template) would be to add a domNode to your layout header definition. So for example, when you are setting the "name" for your column in the layout, you can have something like ...

```
var layout = [
    {
       cells: [
          {
             name:"<i id="sometooltip" class='icon-large icon-edit'></i> Col",
             field: "_item",
             formatter: lang.hitch( this, this.formatter )
          }
       ]
}];
```

What you then want to do is in your formatter, you want to check to see if "sometooltip" has be initialized as a tooltip, and do your connect.. You can use any tooltip.. not just dijit.Tooltip.

There are a few words of caution though. Because the formatter will run every time there is a redraw on your grid, you might want to think up better ways of creating your tooltip. For instance, you might want to add it to `onGridRowHeaderHover`, or you might want to just use CSS3 and use [title] attribute to create a CSS3 header.

Also. You can't just create the tooltip once, because the header is constantly rebuilt every redraw/change of data.

### The Correct Way

The correct way would be to override the Grid template for the header, and include your tooltip in there. You would then extend the header equivalent of `onStyleRow` (which I can't remember), but basically the method that places the headers, and create your tooltip then.

I would definitely use the second option by overriding the template. Because otherwise you will find the grid glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement.  I wanted each DataGrid column header to use the name given to the column as the tooltip since our DataGrids weren't always showing the full column name due to the columns' widths sometimes being squeezed.  I added a monkey patch (below) that is done with an AMD Dojo version:

```js
 require(
  [
"dojo/dom",
"dojox/grid/DataGrid",
"dijit/_Widget",
"dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
"dijit/form/MultiSelect",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"dijit/layout/TabContainer",
"dojox/grid/_Grid",
"dijit/MenuItem",
"dijit/MenuSeparator",
"dojox/grid/_Builder",
"dojox/grid/cells/_base",
"dojox/grid/util",

"dojo/parser",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dojo/ready",
"dojo/query",
"dijit/registry",

  ],
  function(dom, dojox_grid_DataGrid, dijit__Widget, dijit_form_FilteringSelect,
   dijit_form_MultiSelect, dijit_layout_ContentPane, dijit_layout_TabContainer,
   dojox_grid__Grid, MenuItem, MenuSeparator, dojox_grid__Builder,
   dojox_grid_cells__Base, dojox_grid_util,
   
   parser, array, dojoLang, ready, dojoQuery, registry) {

var old_HeaderBuilder_generateHtml = dojox_grid__Builder._HeaderBuilder.prototype.generateHtml; 
dojox_grid__Builder._HeaderBuilder.prototype.generateHtml =  function(inGetValue, inValue){
 var html = this.getTableArray(), cells = this.view.structure.cells;
 
 dojox_grid_util.fire(this.view, "onBeforeRow", [-1, cells]);
 for(var j=0, row; (row=cells[j]); j++){
  if(row.hidden){
   continue;
  }
  html.push(!row.invisible ? '<tr>' : '<tr class="dojoxGridInvisible">');
  for(var i=0, cell, markup; (cell=row[i]); i++){
   cell.customClasses = [];
   cell.customStyles = [];
   if(this.view.simpleStructure){
    if(cell.headerClasses){
     if(cell.headerClasses.indexOf('dojoDndItem') == -1){
      cell.headerClasses += ' dojoDndItem';
     }
    }else{
     cell.headerClasses = 'dojoDndItem';
    }
    if(cell.attrs){
     if(cell.attrs.indexOf("dndType='gridColumn_") == -1){
      cell.attrs += " dndType='gridColumn_" + this.grid.id + "'";
     }
    }else{
     cell.attrs = "dndType='gridColumn_" + this.grid.id + "'";
    }
   }
   markup = this.generateCellMarkup(cell, cell.headerStyles, cell.headerClasses, true);
   // content
     markup[5] = (inValue != undefined ? inValue : inGetValue(cell));
   // set the tooltip for this header to the same name as the header itself
   markup[5] = markup[5].replace("class","title='"+cell.name+"' class");
   // styles
   markup[3] = cell.customStyles.join(';');
   // classes
   markup[1] = cell.customClasses.join(' '); //(cell.customClasses ? ' ' + cell.customClasses : '');
   html.push(markup.join(''));
  }
  html.push('</tr>');
 }
 html.push('</table>');
 return html.join('');
};
   }
   );
```

Note that if there's any chance that any markup may be added to the cell.name then you'll need to add a condition that will somehow extract just the text from it to be the tooltip, or somehow generate a tooltip that won't throw a rendering error, or avoid setting a tooltip altogether for that column.

Answer (score 0):

For a pre-AMD Dojo version this is the monkey patch that we included in our globally scoped javascript resource.  My other answer was after we switched to an AMD Dojo version.

```
// HeaderBuilder.generateHtml
//      If showTooltips is true, the header contents will be used as the tooltip text.
var old_HeaderBuilder_generateHtml = dojox.grid._HeaderBuilder.prototype.generateHtml;  
dojox.grid._HeaderBuilder.prototype.generateHtml =  function(inGetValue, inValue){
    var html = this.getTableArray(), cells = this.view.structure.cells;

    dojox.grid.util.fire(this.view, "onBeforeRow", [-1, cells]);
    for(var j=0, row; (row=cells[j]); j++){
        if(row.hidden){
            continue;
        }
        html.push(!row.invisible ? '<tr>' : '<tr class="dojoxGridInvisible">');
        for(var i=0, cell, markup; (cell=row[i]); i++){
            cell.customClasses = [];
            cell.customStyles = [];
            if(this.view.simpleStructure){
                if(cell.headerClasses){
                    if(cell.headerClasses.indexOf('dojoDndItem') == -1){
                        cell.headerClasses += ' dojoDndItem';
                    }
                }else{
                    cell.headerClasses = 'dojoDndItem';
                }
                if(cell.attrs){
                    if(cell.attrs.indexOf("dndType='gridColumn_") == -1){
                        cell.attrs += " dndType='gridColumn_" + this.grid.id + "'";
                    }
                }else{
                    cell.attrs = "dndType='gridColumn_" + this.grid.id + "'";
                }
            }
            markup = this.generateCellMarkup(cell, cell.headerStyles, cell.headerClasses, true);
            // content
            markup[5] = (inValue != undefined ? inValue : inGetValue(cell));

            // set the tooltip for this header to the same name as the header itself
            try {
                markup[5] = markup[5].replace("class","title='"+cell.name+"' class");
            } catch(e) {
                console.debug(e);
            }
            // styles
            markup[3] = cell.customStyles.join(';');
            // classes
            markup[1] = cell.customClasses.join(' '); //(cell.customClasses ? ' ' + cell.customClasses : '');
            html.push(markup.join(''));
        }
        html.push('</tr>');
    }
    html.push('</table>');
    return html.join('');
};
```